# Get posts in archive page

Tags: get-posts

I am using this code to show posts in columns. How can I set this part ('cat=3&numberposts=5&offset=0') as so archive page should automatically get posts from clicked catagory?

```
<div id="column1">

<?php $posts = get_posts('cat=3&numberposts=5&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "5") { break; } else { ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="<?php _e("bookmark", "solostream"); ?>" title="<?php _e("Permanent Link to", "solostream"); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumb' ); ?></a>
<br><strong><?php the_title(); ?><strong><br>
<?php the_field('price'); ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php $count2++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>

    <div id="column2">

<?php $posts = get_posts('cat=3&numberposts=5&offset=5'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count2 = 0; if ($count2 == "5") { break; } else { ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="<?php _e("bookmark", "solostream"); ?>" title="<?php _e("Permanent Link to", "solostream"); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumb' ); ?></a>
<br><strong><?php the_title(); ?><strong><br>
<?php the_field('price'); ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php $count2++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the number 3, you get the current category by doing the following:

```
$cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
$posts = get_posts('cat='.$cat_ID.'&numberposts=5&offset=0');
```

Comment: fine it worked Tom :)